# What is the correct download address for SP Flash Tool?

Tags: flashtool, mediatek

So far, all the download addresses I can find are from third parties, does MediaTek officially offer downloads?

Comment: https://spflashtools.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no official download source for SP Flash Tool, as Mediatek never released for consumer.